# Trouble with list switch

Tags: python-3.x

I have a trouble with my code and i hope you will have answers.
i have two lists.

```
l1 = ['John','Rachel','Peter']

l2 = ['Rachel,'John','James']
```

I would like to have as output a third list with a count of couples where John, Rachel = Rachel, John. 
so a think like this.
John,Rachel = 2

Rachel,John = 2 (the best way would be to ignore this line because we have already the count above).

Peter, James = 1

These information were on a data frame but i told myself that it would be easier to work on lists.
Tell me if you think if it's a good idea or not.
Thanks a lot for answering. This is my first post and English is not my native language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```py
l1 = ['John','Rachel','Peter']
l2=['Rachel','John','James']
import collections

l=[str(sorted([l1[i], l2[i]]) ) for i in range(min(len(l1), len(l2))) ]

print(collections.Counter(l))
```

Output:

```
Counter({"['John', 'Rachel']": 2, "['James', 'Peter']": 1})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It's exactly what i wanted !  Could you explain me to improve my coding skills?

Comment: Yup, so - first I create list of pairs, where each pair is sorted alphabetically, and then converted to string. To 1. Make (a,b) same as (b,a) (cause both will be translated to (a,b) i.e. alphabetical order) 2. Conversion to string is to make later counting simpler (you can revert it using ```eval``` on keys of the result, depending what's the ultimate, desired output). Then ```Counter``` is simply returning count of unique keys from the input list.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not entirely clear, but would this be a starter?

```
import collections
collections.Counter(l1+l2)
# Counter({'Rachel': 2, 'John': 2, 'Peter': 1, 'James': 1})
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer.
I understand what you did mais it's not what I want, 
I would like to have a count by couples.
like (John,Rachel :2 ) because (john, rachel) and (rachel,john) is the same.

       (Peter,James :1)